# How best to wait until the actor stops in kotlinx.coroutines 0.20?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

In kotlinx.coroutines 0.19, `actor` returns `ActorJob` which can be `join`ed:

```
val myActor = actor<...> { ... }
...
myActor.join()
```

In 0.20, it's changed to return `SendChannel`. Looking at the implementation, it does still return an instance of a class which extends `Job`, so I *could* write

```
...
(myActor as Job).join()
```

but this is an obvious code smell. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: What is your use-case for joining an actor? Do you send an actor some special message that should cause its termination and you want to wait until that message it is processed or do you intent to cancel that actor, forcing it to abort its work, and you want to wait until it closes all resources? What is the underlying reason to wait? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The first (though it isn't a single message, the actor's logic is handle a specific number of messages, then stop and close its resources).

Comment: Of course for this case there is an option of modifying the actor to send a signal using a `Channel` or `CompletableDeferred` when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is creating a `Channel` and then separately `launch`ing a `Job` iterating over this channel.

Comment: It seems to be the best solution for now, until better idioms are provided for this particular use-case.

Comment: This effectively means you gave up using actors, right?